# PhpStorm Drag & Drop files from Explorer

Tags: drag-and-drop, phpstorm

Can you please help, how to drag and drop files from Windows Explorer to the PhpStorm editor?

I have enabled the Drag and Drop feature in settings, but the drag&drop works only for the files from the internal explorer in the left column in the editor.

If I want to drag and drop my html files from my Desktop, or from Windows Explorer, PhpStorm doesn't allow this.

How can I enable this feature? All other editors I ever used had this functionality...

Comment: Drag and Drop to do what? Open such file? Work fine here on Windows 10.

Comment: yes, I want to simply drag a html file from my computer and drop it in the phpStorm editor. It doesn't work for me (Win 10, PHPStorm 2018.2). However there is a text Drop files here, but it works not

Comment: No idea. It just works here -- I drag  some .php/.js/.html file and in Explorer and drop into currently opened PhpStorm editor window -- it opens that file. Maybe you can make some screen cast with how it works for you (http://recordit.co/)? Also, what setting shave you changed?

Comment: I recorder it here http://recordit.co/0EiNCvodzX - I can't drag any file (html neither php). i can drag only from the left column in editor, but not from external explorer or desktop.

Comment: Well ... http://recordit.co/sSAx1OzHns -- I did nothing to enable it, it just works. It might be some Windows setting... No ideas, sorry. It worked even back in 2011 -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2939

Comment: It works for many years: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63836 , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-47696 . Right now -- no idea what it might be. Maybe JetBrains support team can shed some light as they know more how their app works. Anything special about your app/environment? Maybe something in the logs (Help | Show log in ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, thank you all for the answers, I think I found the cause of the issue. I had PHPStorm set to run as administrator. When I removed this setting from the shortcut, now the files are draggable! However this is strange, why the dragging doesn't work in administrator mode, but at least now I know and it works. As spoken with JetBrains support, this is a reported bug.

Comment: That's how Windows works. If you open Notepad as administrator you can't drag files either. Thanks for reporting back.